# Laravel Подзапрос

Tags: laravel5, eloquent

Пользователь выбирает класс и вводит дату, надо вывести все существующие записи для выбранного класса и даты.

```
 $check_class = Lesson::where('class',$class)->where(function ($query) use ($class) {
                  $query->whereBetween('date_start',[$date_start, $date_end])
                  ->orWhereBetween('date_end',[$date_start, $date_end]);
              })->get();
```

Такой запрос выдает

```
"Undefined variable: date_start"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сделал так и все работает)

```
$check_class = Lesson::whereBetween('date_start',[$date_start, $date_end])
      ->orWhereBetween('date_end',[$date_start, $date_end])->where(function ($query) use ($class){
          $query->where('class',$class);
      })->count();
```